# How to add a todo notes in verbatim environment?

Tags: verbatim, todonotes

I need to describe the header of a `.ctl` file. For this purpose, I am using verbatim package for displaying the header. My command lines are below:

```
\begin{verbatim}
dset ^newcase_d01_2612.dat
options  byteswapped
undef 1.e30
title  OUTPUT FROM WRF V3.4 MODEL
\end{verbatim}
```

And now, I would like to add a todo note at each line. As `verbatim` environment erase every command, how can I "cheat" with verbatim and use todo notes environment?

Comment: You'll have to switch to a different environment. Are you okay with that?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with the capabilities of [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,todonotes}

\lstnewenvironment{todoverbatim}[1][]
  {\lstset{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily,
     columns=flexible,
     escapeinside = {/*}{*/}
   }}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
dset ^newcase_d01_2612.dat
options  byteswapped
undef 1.e30
title  OUTPUT FROM WRF V3.4 MODEL
\end{verbatim}

\begin{todoverbatim}
dset ^newcase_d01_2612.dat /*\todo{something 1}*/
options  byteswapped /*\todo{something 2}*/
undef 1.e30 /*\todo{something 3}*/
title  OUTPUT FROM WRF V3.4 MODEL /*\todo{something 4}*/
\end{todoverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Instead of using `verbatim`, you would use `todoverbatim`. The layout is marginally different, and you can modify the escaping characters.

Comment: Thank you so much for your availability, I would have never thought to this solution, I'm trying to put in my code to see if it works

Comment: @Werner: What about \let\verbatim\relax
\let\endverbatim\relax
\lstnewenvironment{verbatim}[1][]
  {\lstset{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily,
     columns=flexible,
     escapeinside = {/*}{*/}
   }}
  {}